# Add gradient to text color of different size

Tags: php, image

I want to apply a gradient background to text. I mean the actual text, not the background the text is shown on. So if the gradient was a red to white and the text was just the letter T, then the T would be filled in with red to white.

I found some code that allows this to be done and it works well. The problem is that the text can only be as wide as the gradient. So if the gradient is 90 pixels wide, the text entered is 10 characters and the font used has a character width of 8 pixels, the full text will display with the gradient background. But if the text is increased to 11 characters, that exceeds the size of the image so not all of it shows.

I'm trying to use the imagecopyresampled function to create a new image that has the width I need. It creates the image but it is not uniform - there are dark spots not in the original. Plus, if the text consists of a large number of characters, the result image is very large and takes a long time to create.

The only other way I can think of is to create large copies of the gradient images and just use them. That works but the new image has to be large enough to fit all possible entries of text. I did try using background-repeat and that sort of worked. But there spaces between the repeats.

The code I am using is below. Can someone see a better way of doing this?

```
    <style>.grads {                     
     display:block; 
     -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
     background: -webkit-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
     url(newimg.jpg) no-repeat; 
     background: -o-linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
     -webkit-background-clip: text;  
    } 
    </style> 

    $filename = 'gold.jpg';
    $percent = 100;

    // Get new dimensions
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
    $new_width = $width * $percent;
    $new_height = $height * $percent;

    // Resample
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);

    // Output
    imagejpeg($image_p, 'newimg.jpg');

    <div><div class="grads">
      <span>Hellow</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should add tags according to the languages involved.

Comment: Write the letters on a simple background and see how large they are. Resize your gradient to that same size and then write the letters onto it.

Comment: You should ask about text color.

Comment: Mark - That's what I am trying to do. It works but the size of the image for long text takes about 5-10 seconds to complete and that's not good. I may be able to get that time down by limiting the height but, as mentioned, the resulting image is not a uniform gradient. The beginning of it may be all black and then a good part will be the gradient and then some more black sections occur.

Comment: I don't understand what this means: "You should ask about text color"